# Mathematics behind Babylonian Square Root method

Tags: algorithm, math

I read the method to calculate the square root of any number and the algorithm is as follows:

```
double findSquareRoot(int n) {
    double x = n;
    double y = 1;
    double e = 0.00001;
    while(x-y >= e) {
        x = (x+y)/2;
        y = n/x;
    }
    return x;
}
```

**My question regarding this method are**

1. How it calculates the square root? I didn't understand the mathematics behind this. How `x=(x+y)/2 and y=n/x` converges to square root of n. Explain this mathematics.
2. What is the complexity of this algorithm?

Comment: I think this would be a question for [math.se] instead.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is purely about mathematics.

Comment: This algorithm, attributed to Heron of Alexandria, is used to excellent effect in the [classic lectures by Abelson and Sussman: Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-001-structure-and-interpretation-of-computer-programs-spring-2005/video-lectures/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is easy to see if you do some runs and print the successive values of x and y. For example for 100:

```
50.5 1.9801980198019802
26.24009900990099 3.8109612300726345
15.025530119986813 6.655339226067038
10.840434673026925 9.224722348894286
10.032578510960604 9.96752728032478
10.000052895642693 9.999947104637101
10.000000000139897 9.999999999860103
```

See, the trick is that if `x` is **not** the square root of `n`, then it is above or below the real root, and `n/x` is always on the other side. So if you calculate the midpoint of `x` and `n/x` it will be somewhat nearer to the real root.

And about the complexity, it is actually unbounded, because the real root will never reached. That's why you have the `e` parameter.

Comment: Is it possible to calculate the complexity in terms of n and x ?

Comment: To be precise, the midpoint `(x+y)/2` will not be "nearer to the real root" (than which one? `x` or `y`?).  It will be nearer to the real root than the **worst** of the approximations `x` and `y`.  So, your worst approximation converges to the real root and, when `x` and `y` are close enough, you're done.

Comment: @devsda: No, as I said, the complexity would be unbounded in terms of `x`, and `n` is not an input parameter. However you can calculate it in terms of `e`: according to Wikipedia (already linked in other answers) the number of correct digits of `x` doubles each iteration, so it would be something along the lines of `O(log(-log(e)))`, but I'm unsure about the details.

Answer (score 3):

This is a typical application of [Newton's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) for calculating the square root of `n`.  You're calculating the limit of the sequence:

```
x_0 = n
x_{i+1} = (x_i + n / x_i) / 2
```

Your variable `x` is the current term `x_i` and your variable `y` is `n / x_i`.

To understand why you have to calculate this limit, you need to think of the function:

```
f(x) = x^2 - n
```

You want to find the root of this function.  Its derivative is

```
f'(x) = 2 * x
```

and Newton's method gives you the formula:

```
x_{i+1} = x_i - f(x_i) / f'(x_1) = ... = (x_i + n / x_i) / 2
```

---

For completeness, I'm copying here the rationale from @rodrigo's answer, combined with my comment to it.  This is helpful if you want to forget about Newton's method and try to understand this algorithm alone.

> The trick is that if `x` is not the square root of `n`, then it is
>   an approximation which lies either above or below the real root, and `y = n/x` is always on the
>   other side.  So if you calculate the midpoint of `(x+y)/2`, it will be
>   nearer to the real root than the worst of these two approximations
>   (`x` or `y`).  When `x` and `y` are close enough, you're done.

This will also help you find the complexity of the algorithm.  Say that `d` is the distance of the worst of the two approximations to the real root `r`.  Then the distance between the midpoint `(x+y)/2` and `r` is at most `d/2` (it will help you if you draw a line to visualize this).  This means that, with each iteration, the distance is halved.  Therefore, the worst-case complexity is logarithmic w.r.t. to the distance of the initial approximation and the precision that is sought.  For the given program, it is

```
log(|n-sqrt(n)|/epsilon)
```

Comment: nickie is correct.  Substitute the f(x) = x^2 - n into newtons method and work out all the derivatives and simplify the result.  It becomes just itteratively taking the average of current estimate x and n/x, which becomes the new estimate x.

Comment: @nickie Can you please explain the last statement of your answer ?

Comment: Worst case complexity? That would apply only if the function were a completely general one. This is NOT bisection on a general function. Since this is a known function that will always converge under the Newton's method iterations, it will exhibit quadratic convergence.

Comment: @woodchips: I think we're talking about different things here.  Quadratic on what?  Is there a mistake in my answer and where exactly is that?

Answer (score 1):

I think all information can be [found in wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Babylonian_method).

The basic idea is that if x is an overestimate to the square root of a non-negative real number S then S/x, will be an underestimate and so the average of these two numbers may reasonably be expected to provide a better approximation.

With each iteration this algorithm doubles correct digits in answer, so complexity is linear to desired accuracy's logarithm.

Why does it work? As stated [here](http://www.had2know.com/academics/babylonian-algorithm-square-root.html), if you will do infinite iterations you'll get some value, let's name it L. L has to satisfy equasion L = (L + N/L)/2  (as in algorithm), so L = sqrt(N). If you're worried about convergence, you may calculate squared relative errors for each iteration (Ek is error, Ak is computed value):

Ek = (Ak/sqrt(N) - 1)²
if:
Ak = (Ak-1 + N/Ak-1)/2 and Ak = sqrt(N)(sqrt(Ek) + 1)
you may derive recurrence relation for Ek:
Ek = Ek-1²/[4(sqrt(Ek-1) + 1)²]
and limit of it is 0, so limit of A1,A2... sequence is sqrt(N).

Answer (score 1):

The mathematical explanation is that, over a small range, the arithmetic mean is a reasonable approximation to the geometric mean, which is used to calculate the square root. As the iterations get closer to the true square root, the difference between the arithmetic mean and the geometric mean vanishes, and the approximation gets very close. Here is my favorite version of Heron's algorithm, which first normalizes the input *n* over the range 1 ≤ *n* < 4, then unrolls the loop for a fixed number of iterations that is guaranteed to converge.

```
def root(n):
    if n < 1: return root(n*4) / 2
    if 4 <= n: return root(n/4) * 2
    x = (n+1) / 2
    x = (x + n/x) / 2
    x = (x + n/x) / 2
    x = (x + n/x) / 2
    x = (x + n/x) / 2
    x = (x + n/x) / 2
    return x
```

I discuss several programs to calculate the square root at [my blog](http://programmingpraxis.com/2012/06/01/square-roots/).

Comment: @Quetzalcoatl: Thanks for noticing. Fixed. I was writing some Scheme code this morning, in case you couldn't tell. The program above now runs properly in Python.

Comment: I immediatelly thought of Lisp, but wouldn't guess Scheme just by that ;)